# cant show the result of rss feed with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, rss

I use fragment to run recycleView  but contained errors.
it seems there is an error in the adapter.
this is a fragment. i call ReadRss class in here.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootViewss = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentinspirasibisnis,container,false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootViewss.findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(getActivity(),recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();
    return rootViewss;
}
```

and I call the adapter in this ReadRss file

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(4));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this adapter file. maybe possible errors in viewholder.

```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
Context context;
public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems){
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_new_rows_item,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final FeedItem current = feedItems.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.date.setText(current.getPubDate());
    holder.description.setText(current.getDescription());
    Picasso.with(context).load(current.getThumbnailUrl()).into(holder.Thumbnails);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("Link",current.getLink());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title , date, description;
    ImageView Thumbnails;
    CardView cardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
        Thumbnails = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
    }
}}
```

i have error like this

```
Failure getting entry for 0x7f020061 (t=1 e=97) in package 0 (error -75)
08-18 01:34:33.817 2355-2355/com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-18 01:34:33.817 2355-2355/com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xaf79bb20)
08-18 01:34:33.857 2355-2355/com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp, PID: 2355
                                                                          android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                              at com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:29)
                                                                              at com.jdev.anonymous.hahaapp.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:20)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1170)
                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
```

Comment: you can post the error too

Comment: ok. everyone help please :'(

Comment: I think my problem has been solved with just using image inside linearlayout